# Not getting Lat and Long through either GPS or Network

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener

I am trying to get location using `GPS provider` or `Network provider` but i didn't get location from either **GPS** or **Network**.
Here is my code which was working fine some days ago but now it's not working.
I don't understand where i am wrong because all permission are already added in **AndroidManifest.xml**.
Here is the code which helpful for you to understand.

```
public class SearchDishoom extends Header implements LocationListener {  
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchdish);        




        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000000, 100, this);

            locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            };              

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            // if gps provider is not enable then popup alertbox
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        } else {        
            // if gps is one then start searching
            locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            };
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000000,100, locationListenerGps);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Get location (lat-long) from sharedpreference to further use
     */
    prefLocation = getSharedPreferences("myLocation", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String userLocationLat1 = prefLocation.getString("Lat", String.valueOf(0));
    String userLocationlong1 = prefLocation.getString("Long", String.valueOf(0));
    String address = prefLocation.getString("Address", "Location not found not found");
    userLocationLat = Double.parseDouble(userLocationLat1);
    userLocationlong = Double.parseDouble(userLocationlong1);

    // set lat-long value in getset class for use of another activity
    gs = new GetSet();
    gs.setLatitude(userLocationLat);
    gs.setLangitude(userLocationlong);      
    if (userLocationLat == 0 && userLocationlong == 0 && address.equals("")) {
        /*
         *  if lat-long is 0 or null then start searching using
         *  GPS Provider or Network Provider
         */

        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        } else {
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000000,100, locationListenerGps);             
        }
    } else {
        // set lat-long value in getset class for use of another activity
        gs.setLatitude(userLocationLat);
        gs.setLangitude(userLocationlong);
        setLocationName(userLocationLat, userLocationlong);
    }       
}
```

Here is override onLocationchanged():

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    userLocationLat =location.getLatitude();
    userLocationlong =location.getLongitude();
    prefLocation = getSharedPreferences("myLocation", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefLocation.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("Lat", String.valueOf(userLocationLat));
    prefsEditor.putString("Long", String.valueOf(userLocationlong));

    gs.setLatitude(userLocationLat);
    gs.setLangitude(userLocationlong);
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = new Geocoder(SearchDishoom.this, Locale.getDefault())
                .getFromLocation(userLocationLat, userLocationlong, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        city = obj.getLocality();
        addressString = add + "," + city;
        gs.setCurrentAddressString(addressString);
        prefsEditor.putString("Address", addressString);
        prefsEditor.commit();
        tvLocation.setText(add + "," + city);           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        showToast("Unable to find location");
    }
}
```

Even i am not getting location using `Geocoder`, If i enter city name then it show me "Unable to find location".
Here is trick, `GeoCoder` is working on Emulator but not working on phone(i tried 2 different handset).

My project is build in `API 17` and no any logcat error.
Please give me any hint or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check "location access" settings and allow access to your location?..

Answer (score 0):

While I cant immediately tell whats wrong with your code, you should consider maybe using a location library and let others do the heavy lifting. See: https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/